# ClassCastException when trying to cast a subclass

Tags: java, casting

I have this code:

```
package Maven_test.Maven_project_test;

public class Test {
    class A {
        int i = 10;
    }

    class B extends A {
        int j = 20;
    }

    class C extends B {
        int k = 30;
    }

    public void pruebaJerarquia() {
        A a = new B();
        B b = (B) a;
        C c = (C) b;

        System.out.println(c.k);
    }
}
```

and I'd like to know why this line:

```
C c = (C) b;
```

throws this exception when executing the program:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: 
Maven_test.Maven_project_test.Test$B cannot be cast to 
Maven_test.Maven_project_test.Test$C
    at Maven_test.Maven_project_test.Test.pruebaJerarquia(Test.java:21)
    at Maven_test.Maven_project_test.App.main(App.java:10)
```

I think it has something to do with upcasting and downcasting, but I don't get it. Could it be because "b" is pointing to "a" and with "C c = (C) b" it's like trying to cast something like this?

```
C c = new A();
```

Thank you!

Comment: Because `b` is not a `C`.

Comment: I don't believe you understand how casting work, Every `c` is a `b` but no `b` is a `c`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are creating one object of type `B`. As per your class hierarchy, each `B` object is also an `A`, but not a `C`.

Now let's look on how to assign the reference to this `B` object to various variables:

```
Object o = new B(); // You can always assign references to an Object-typed variable.
A a = (A) o; // This works because the object is of type A.
B b = (B) o; // This works because the object is of type B.
C c = (C) o; // This does not work because the object is not of type C.
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This "You are creating one object of type B" was the key for me to finally get it.

Answer (score 1):

Because theoretically `B` can be a `C` but not always a `C`.

```
B b = new C ();
```

Down casting is not a good idea. You better include a check every time you cast.

```
if ( b instanceof C) {
    C c = (C) b;
}
```